# ATtiny85 + HC-05 + Oled = smart watch

Tags: i2c, softwareserial, attiny, hc-05

I am using an ATtiny85 for making a smart watch. Bluetooth module HC-05 with ATtiny85 pins PB3->TX, PB4->RX and it works. Secondly I have connected a 0.96" OLED on PB0 (SDA) and PB2 (SCL) and this is also working perfectly. But once I combine both things, it doesn't work.

Comment: Why did you decide to use an AVR without a hardware UART?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: suggest me an alternate 8 pin micro-controller with I2C and UART hardware.

Comment: @Vipin Why 8 pin?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Probably because he's not aware of the excellent offerings by Microchip in 8-pin MCUs with hardware I2C and UART, such as the PIC12F1840 - though why you'd cripple yourself with just 8 pins is beyond me when you can get a PIC32 in a 28-pin QFN package that is smaller than those old fashioned chunky DIP things and about 100x more powerful...

Comment: @Majenko: to keep the size of overall device as small as possible. I just need to hook 1 oled (two pins over I2C) and 1 bluetooth module (two pins) thats it. One more thing, should be able to hold glyph( font), flash > 8kB